# Nginx 301 redirect from a page to another

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

I am looking for a way to do 301 redirection from one page to another.

`site.com/page-1` should redirect to `site.com` without affecting other pages and directories.

I'm new to Nginx, please let me know which is the configuration file that I need to modify? What is the syntax to do the above redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
location /page-1 {
   rewrite ^/page-1$ http://$server_name permanent;
 }
```

Comment: In which file to place this?

Comment: In your Nginx configuration file

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer using `return` over `rewrite` when redirecting

```
location /page-1 {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host;
}
```

You need to add this in the virtual host file you created before, you'll probably find it inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`